# why does EventWaitHandle not work?

Tags: c#, threadpool

I have two functions named ChangeText() & ChangeColor(), the first function called ChangeText who will loading a large number of data into memory, it will cost a lot of time, So I run it asynchorously; the other one is called ChangeColor who will change the button's color when data loading ok, so there is an order to run these two functions: ChangeText first and ChangeColor second.  here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace ThreadSynchorous
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        asyncInvoke = new AsyncInvoke();
    }
    AsyncInvoke asyncInvoke;
    EventWaitHandle waitMeHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false,EventResetMode.ManualReset);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
        {
            asyncInvoke.BeginAsync(ChangeText);
        }), null);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
        {
            asyncInvoke.BeginAsync(ChangeColor);
        }), null);

        label1.Content += " \r\n-------------------------\r\n";
    }

    private bool ChangeText()
    {
        waitMeHandle.Reset();
        this.button1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(delegate()
        {
            string filename = @"C:\EXO.txt";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default))
            {
                string result;
                while ((result = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //here perform action
                }
            }

            label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(delegate
            {
                label1.Content += "Loading finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName="+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()+") ";
                waitMeHandle.Set();
                return true;
            }));
            waitMeHandle.Set();
            return true;
        }));
        waitMeHandle.Set();
        return true;
    }

    private bool ChangeColor()
    {
        waitMeHandle.WaitOne();
        this.button1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(delegate()
        {
            this.button1.Background = Brushes.Red;

            label1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<bool>(delegate()
            {
                label1.Content += "Coloring finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName="+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId+") ";
                return true;
            }));

            return true;
        }));
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

here is the class of AsyncInvoke:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ThreadSynchorous
{
    public  class AsyncInvoke
    {
        public void BeginAsync(Func<bool> MyFunction)
        {
            Func<bool> func = new Func<bool>(MyFunction);
            IAsyncResult iar = func.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(EndAsync), func);
        }

        public void EndAsync(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            Func<bool> func = (Func<bool>)iar.AsyncState;
            func.EndInvoke(iar);
        }
    }
}
```

I planed to use EventWaitHandle to sync these two functions, but the result is that these two function will still running in a mess order: sometimes ChangeText() function first, sometimes ChangeColor() first. I just so confused.

And also, I use ThreadPool to start these two function, but why I got the same threadID like below:
Loading finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName=10) Coloring finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName=10)

I thought that the Thread.CurrentThreadName will be different because I use the threadpool!!! why?  thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        asyncInvoke = new AsyncInvoke();
    }
    AsyncInvoke asyncInvoke;
    EventWaitHandle waitMeHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
        {
            asyncInvoke.BeginAsync(ChangeText);
        }), null);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate(object state)
        {
            asyncInvoke.BeginAsync(ChangeColor);
        }), null);

        label1.Content += " \r\n-------------------------\r\n";
    }

    private bool ChangeText()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ChangeText");         

        //do your time-consuming operation here, controls' delegated are for UI updates only

        this.button1.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(()=>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Button invoker");
            //update button here


            //what was bool return type for?
            label1.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                label1.Content += "Loading finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + ") ";
                waitMeHandle.Set();
            }));

        }));


        //waitMeHandle.Set(); - here's your guilty - button delegate runs asynchrounously so you had absolutely no guarantee that it's done as your app reach this line
        return true;
    }

    private bool ChangeColor()
    {
        waitMeHandle.WaitOne();
        Debug.WriteLine("ChangeColor");
        this.button1.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            this.button1.Background = Brushes.Red;

            label1.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                label1.Content += "Coloring finish!(Thread.CurrentThreadName=" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ") ";
                waitMeHandle.Reset(); //you've consumed your event here so this is the place to reset it
            }));
        }));
        return true;
    }
}
```

See code snippet above -it should explain you a bit. And of course, you've got same thread name because you dispatch label delegate to UI thread - that's the primary reason you shouldn't do any lengthy operations there like you did initially

Comment: Hi grzegorz_p, actually this is a sample, but in real work, the ChangeColor function will pick out a lot of data and make a comparison with the old txt file,then it will color the data same to the old one. So here I just run the function separately. thx for your reply :)

Comment: i've done a little investigation and it seems we have a guilty :)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. I think we should use  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>ChangeText()); 
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=>ChangeColor());  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question (I see other possible issues on the code) I would try to set the Event Handler on construction and remove the `waitMeHandle.Reset();` of the `Change_Text` method.

As you're launching the two processes in parallel you can not be sure that `Change_Text` will be executed first.

Comment: Thx for SoMos's reply, well, after removing the waitMeHandle.Reset(); it will still not work properly. even through the two processes run in parallel, why I still cann't using EventWaitHandle to control? Do you have some good solution for this? like using mutex or join or any other else ? would you pls point out the possible issues ? thx  :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the question regarding the name of the executing thread goes:

If you call `Dispatcher.Invoke` then the specified delegate will be executed on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with. In your case probably the UI thread.

See the remarks section on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx):

> In WPF, only the thread that created a DispatcherObject may access that object. For example, a background thread that is spun off from the main UI thread cannot update the contents of a Button that was created on the UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either Invoke or BeginInvoke.

Next, you are overdoing things. If you call `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` you are scheduling a delegate to execute on a ThreadPool thread. Now in your code, if within the method that gets executed on the ThreadPool thread, you call `Func<T>.BeginInvoke`, then again you schedule a delegate to get executed on a ThreadPool thread. So just changing your code to this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ChangeText());

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ChangeColor());

        label1.Content += " \r\n-------------------------\r\n";
    }
```

Is sufficient for executing `ChangeText` and `ChangeColor` on ThreadPool threads.

Comment: oh... thx afrischke, I got to know why the threadname is the same. and I do a test , just write  MessageBox.Show(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());   int front of the ChangeText function & ChangeColor function, it shows me the ThreadId is 7 and 12. Got it, thx.

Comment: thx for your help, now all the problems are solved. very appreciate your work. :)